# Bug #1966203: Ubuntu 22.04 won't boot any more

Tags: boot

I have Ubuntu 22.04 on a Lenovo M710q which worked fine for about 4 weeks and then it stopped booting.

I have these error messages:

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

That led me to this Launchpad bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1966203. It describes exactly my problem.

Comment: The information at the link you gave for the bug shows it is being worked on. Till fixed nothing anyone can do.

Comment: Generally, the way to fix a bug is: learn to code, get the source, study the problem, edit the source, recompile and test, etc.

Comment: This seems in connection with snap. Could this be worked around by removing snap?

Comment: Strong Personal Opinion; there are too many issues with snap packages, ... *(fill in the  strong words you prefer here)*

Comment: @vanadium not if the component in use is not available as a non-snap.  In this case, I would say they have to wait for the bug to be fixed.